# Nhibernate 3 : Retrieve a list in a n-n relation

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have three tables : Tool, Color and ColorTool.
ColorTool has 3 columns : the id (auto increment) and IdTool + IdColor.

I have a `List<Tool>` and my goal is to retrieve a `List<Color>` or a `List<int>` (just the IdColor).

My last try :

```
var colorList = (from res in toolList select res.ToolColor.ToList()).ToList();
```

In this case colorList is a List of List of ToolColor.

I don't know how retrieve that data. Can someone help me ? I use nhibernate 3.1 ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
from res in toolList
from toolColor in res.ToolColor
select toolColor.Color
```

?